# How to unzip a string zipped by SharpZipLib in winrt?

Tags: c#, zip, windows-runtime

I couldn't find a WinRT version of SharpZipLib and System.IO.Compression.GZipStream can't unzip Zip streams.

Comment: Perhaps things have changed since 2012... but GZipStream and unzip streams. Updating my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Does SharpZipLib [source](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/Download.aspx) compile on WinRT>

Comment: Unfortunately not. Many classes and references are missing.

Answer (score -2):

SharpZipLib is purely a managed library. The same binary should be usable on WinRT. If not, just compile the source yourself for your target platform.

Failing that, check out DotNetZip - http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

Comment: Just because a library is purely managed code it doesn't mean it can be compiled in any platform. WinRT is very different from .net4 and the windows phone. I tried before asking, it uses many classes not present in WinRT. Same for DotNetZip.

Comment: How about system.io.compression.ziparchive? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx Requires v4.5 of the framework though.